# ASP.NET validate

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to validate an ASP.NET text box with min char=3, max=10 and no special characters. I do not want to use a jQuery plugin. I would rather use plain jQuery.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, you can use the validate control, either with a custom validator or a reg ex validator.

Something like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Error error..."
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Static" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I want to use jQuery and do it

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a RegularExpressionValidator with the Regex pattern "`[\w]{3, 10}`" ?

Comment: I want to use jQuery and do it

Comment: But why, if I may ask? They both are an abstraction of basic Javascript.